# Change base URL in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, base-url

The website was build with CodeIgniter. This is accessible by typing https://test.mysite.eu.

I tried to change the base URL to remove the '**test**', I found this [documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/codeigniter/codeigniter_configuration.htm) and changed the following config file `application/config/config.php`

I changed this

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://test.mysite.eu/';
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://mysite.eu/';
```

And then, everything failed. The website is not accessible anymore.

When I try to access to https://test.mysite.eu/, this redirect me to https://mysite.eu/ but the browser display this error message : Address not found.

Should I change something more? Clear a cache?
I am pretty new to CodeIgniter so sorry for my lack of competence.

### The .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /       
    RewriteCond $1 !^(themes)   
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|static|img|css|js|map|favicon\.ico)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]       
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <filesMatch "\.(js|css|png)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </filesMatch>
</IfModule>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/ico text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/javascript application/x-javascript application/x-httpd-php application/rss+xml application/atom_xml text/javascript
```

Comment: Its part of your subdomain so you can not remove it

Comment: https://mysite.eu is working before you do that change? I mean, that domain is pointing to your server/hosting?

Comment: @Kamae I do not really care of the DNS redirection for now. I just want that the code rewrite the correct URL. And no mysite.eu is not used yet.

In fact, I continue to use test.mysite.eu (wich is pointing to my server). But this server is not displaying correctly the website since I edited the base URL

Comment: What I mean is if mysite.eu it's working for you or not. If mysite.eu is not live yet, do you have mysite.eu with the test IP in you hosts file? If not, obviously doesn't work because your browser can't access to mysite.eu. You said it is redirecting from test.mysite.eu to mysite.eu so Code Igniter seems to be doing the work fine

Comment: Another thing, can you please check in application/config/routes.php there is not any reference to test.mysite.eu ?

Answer (score 0):

add this code in .htaccess file.

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.mysite\.eu
  RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mysite\.eu\/" [R=301,L]
```